# How to add another Value to this Example in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

How can i add another Value / Parameter / Variable  to this Example ?

```
Dim pricesList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
pricesList.AddRange({New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("$5", "1"),
                     New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("$3", "2")})

For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In pricesList
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Price: {0}, Value {1}", item.Key, item.Value))
Next item
```

So that i get something like

```
Dim pricesList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
pricesList.AddRange({New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("$5", "1","1","1"),
                     New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("$3", "2","2","2")})

For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In pricesList
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Price: {0}, Value {1}, Value {1}, Value {1}, Value {1}", item.Key, item.Value))
Next item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an array to `String.Format` and have the different elements of the array replace different parameters in your string. You can do something like the following. Note that I changed the `List (Of KeyValuePair)` to a `Dictionary` as that seems to make more sense. As both the keys and the values seem to be integers, you might also want to use integer (or some kind of numeric) values rather than strings.

**[Edit]** in response to a comment, added a statement to show an example of adding an item to the Dictionary using values from TextBoxes.

```
Dim pricesList As New Dictionary(Of String, String()) _
    From {{"$5", {"1", "1", "1"}}, {"$3", {"2", "2", "2"}}}

pricesList.Add(PriceTextBox.Text, {V1TextBox.Text, V2TextBox.Text, V3TextBox.Text})

For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String()) In pricesList
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Price: {0}, Value {1}, Value {2}, Value {3}", item.Key, item.Value(0), item.Value(1), item.Value(2)))
Next item
```

Comment: How can i add now something to this ?

Comment: If you mean how do you add a third key to the Dictionary, change the `From` clause to `From {{"$5", {"1", "1", "1"}}, {"$3", {"2", "2", "2"}}, {"$1", {"3", "3", "3"}}}`. If you mean how do you have four values instead of three in each Dictionary value, just add another element to the array. For example, change the first Dictionary item from `{"$5", {"1", "1", "1"}}` to `{"$5", {"1", "1", "1", "1"}}` etc. and add a fourth item to your `String.Format` statement.

Comment: ahh :) i mean how can i add it on a other place in my Script ... 
For complete Explain ... I need to get the Values from Textboxes ... and add it for each button press ..  and then in the for each loop which is working atm i need to echo them later...

Comment: @Hanselman This doesn't seem to be related to your original question, but I have updated the answer to show an example of how to add an item to the Dictionary using values from TextBoxes.

Comment: Thanks its really hard to explain but this is what i mean i will test it :) Thank you really !

Comment: Ahhrg it isnt that what i want at least :(  @Blackwood do  you have skype or something to help me ? ... And i will open a detailed Question... again

Comment: @Hanselman I suggest you edit your question to describe what it is you want to do.